# Rest - How to download PDF for mobile

Tags: java, android, iphone, pdf, jax-rs

I have only tested this on android and iphone.

We have a web application where the user can download a pdf file
This works on a laptop, but when I push the link on android or iphone nothing the download starts, but the pdf is never shown or downloaded.

I have tried many different variants in the Content-Disposition Header, but nothing so far works.

Any ideas?

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response showPDF(@Context HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        byte[] dokument = somePDF();

        return Response.ok(dokument)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "inline;filename=\"kvittering.PDF\"")
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, dokument.length)
                .build();
    }
```

I have tried all these, but same behavior:

```
.header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "inline; filename=\"kvittering.PDF\"")
.header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,"inline;filename=\"kvittering.PDF\"")
.header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"kvittering.PDF\"")
.header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"kvittering.PDF\"")
.header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "inline; filename=kvittering.pdf")
```

I have also tried
`@Produces("application/pdf")` with the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we figured it out. Haven't verified it yet though, but will post an answer and accept once it is verified.

It seems our staging server uses an invalid ssl certificate, and android doesn't like that. I believe thats why it is not working.

I will try to install the certificate on the phone and try again.

Answer (score 0):

so [here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/download-pdf-file-from-jax-rs/) you have a tutorial on this from mkyong

the main difference seems to be the @Produces annotation settings

```
@Produces("application/pdf")
```

Full code:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;

@Path("/pdf")
public class PdfService {

    private static final String FILE_PATH = "c:\\Android-Book.pdf";

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces("application/pdf")
    public Response getFile() {

        File file = new File(FILE_PATH);

        ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
        response.header("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename=new-android-book.pdf");
        return response.build();

    }

}
```

For me this works, but the download is an xml file thus I use:

```
@Produces("application/xml")
```

Comment: I have seen this. I am trying application/pdf now to see if it helps. He is using a file from the filesystem, whilst I have a byte. I don't know if it makes any different.

Comment: I think that what makes sense in your case would be the produces setting.

Comment: return Response.ok().entity(streamingOutput)
                        .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + reportXML.getName() + ".xml").build();

this is how I set the content disposition. Might be that it's not correctly set up

Comment: It looks pretty much the same as our code. Your streamingOutput is that a file on the filesystem?

Comment: it is a StreamingOutput object, make it xml, the return type, just for curiosity purposes, see if that works